# What is the cardinality of the smallest non-trivial set of all functions that have that set as domain and codomain?

Tags: functions, set-theory

Let's consider a set where every element of that set is a function that maps it onto itself.

There is at least one set that satisfies this constraint, and it has a cardinality of one: the set that contains just one function $f$, defined as $f(f)=f$.

Are there any larger sets with the same property? If so, what is their cardinality?

Comment: I am pretty sure that in ZFC with Kuratowsky's pair it can be proved that there is no function $f$ such that $f(f)=f$.

Comment: Does this not violate the axiom of foundation? If $S = \{f\}$, then $f = S \times S$, so $S \times S \in S$.

Comment: As others have noted in the comments above, in ZFC there is only one such set: the empty set is a set of functions $\emptyset\to\emptyset$. The axiom of foundation / regularity rules out any nonempty sets with this property. On the other hand, if you just want a set $X$ and a bijection between $X$ and a set of functions $X\to X$ (so each element of $X$ "codes" a function), then every set admits such a bijection: consider constant functions.